# Get profile pictures of all users in SharePoint hosted app (SharePoint online Office 365) issue in IE

Tags: angularjs, office365, sharepoint-online

I have created a SharePoint Hosted app to display all users (based on Search). Now the problem is that the profile pictures are not loaded in IE/Edge. (In Chrome it works).

But when I visit the location of the profile pictures in IE/Edge and refresh my app page it all works.. Location of profile pictures: :  https://testdomain-my.sharepoint.com/User Photos/Profile Pictures/firstnameUser_lastnameUser_testdomainname_com_MThumb.jpg

Have someone an idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can Visit any user's Delve site. From there you can get User's display picture URL.Then you can format remaining user's Image URL in this format instaed of using "testdomain-my" URL format.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I just test it with the delve profile picture URL and I got still the same issue.. It's not loading until I visit the url manually, in this case it's this URL that I am using : domain/_vti_bin/DelveApi.ashx/people/profileimage?userId={{user.email}}&size=L , is this the URL that you mean?